# Generic Enums in Java

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a basic Configuration class that provides all its possible keys and the type of the corresponding value types in an enum like so:

```
public class Configuration {
    public static enum Key {
        FIRST_KEY("actual key 1", Long.class),
        ANOTHER_KEY("actual key 2", Integer.class)

        public final String value;
        public final Class type;

        Key(String value, Class type) {
            this.value = value;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is write a method that parses the value of a given key from a String and returns the value as the appropriate type. Basically this:

```
public <T> T getValue(Key<T> key, String valueStr);
```

This attempt fails at the method declaration already, since its appears that Enums in Java can not have type arguments. Any ideas on how to achieve something similar to this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use an enum instead of a simple factory pattern that would let you have paramaterized types?

Comment: No there isn't. I like enums for their compact and intuitive syntax, but will probably resort to a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply

```
public <T> T getValue(Key key, String valueStr);
```

It lacks compile time checking though, so this will pass compile

```
Short value = getValue(FIRST_KEY, string);  // should be Long
```

The better answer? Don't use `enum`! Make `Key<T>` an ordinary class.

```
public static class Key<T>
{
    public static final Key<Long> FIRST_KEY 
                  = new Key("actual key 1", Long.class);
    ...

    public final String value;
    public final Class<T> type;

    Key(String value, Class<T> type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this actually works. Type erasure is a funny thing. This approach sort of negates the whole idea of using type variables though.
Now how do I best extract the actual type to figure out what I need to parse? Use a bunch of if (key.type.newInstance() instanceof XY) ?

Comment: Another question: How does the compiler infer the actual value of T in this case? What is the return value after compilation?

Comment: `if(key.type==Long.class){ parse string as long } ...`

Answer (score 2):

I'd provide a type hint in the `getValue()` method, e.g.

```
public <T> T getValue(Key k, Class<T> type);
```

You can check if the type is correct inside the method by checking the key.

Comment: Thanks David, this looks like it would work well, but I don't like the overhead of having to pass the additional type parameter. I already know the type from the Key enum.
Am I correct to assume there is no way of extracting it?

Comment: You could use a separate enum for each type, e.g. `enum LongKey implements Key<Long>`, but that just looks broken.

Comment: It does indeed :) It looks like I'm going the traditional route of having separate get*() methods for each type. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can initialyze a Map<Class, String>, and add a method for this.

*EDIT after comments*

`Map<Class, Enum>`, give `FIRST_KEY` for a `get(objectParameter.getClass())`, if objectParameter is a Long

Naturally, if Long have more than one  key : 
`Map<Class, Set< Enum>>` and choose in the result from the environment you are working.

Comment: I add a "reverse table" when I need to check some unknown parameter : in this post : if the object is `Long` then the key I've to use is `"actual key 1"`.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question - how can the OP map from a type token `Class<T>` to a `T` instance using an enum or a similar pattern?

Comment: There can be multiple Keys with values of the same type. I should have clarified it in the listing above.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass the class of enum as parameter:

```
public <T extends Enum> T getValue(key, Class<T extends Enum> enumClazz) {
    return enumClazz.cast(...);
}
```

Comment: An enum instance is already passed in - the OP wants to return an instance of the type it represents. Anyway `T` should be declared `T extends Enum<T>`

Answer (score -1):

Have a getType method in your Enum, then use that to help cast your string.

getType() in the Enum.

```
 public Class getType()
 {      
    return type;    
 }
```

Using the getType() method to help cast the string.

```
 public Object getValue(Key key , String strValue)
 {
    return key.getType().cast(strValue) ;   
 }
```

You might have to write an IF statement to work out how to parse the String for different objects e.g. for Integer use the Integer.parseInt(s) method, otherwise you'll get a ClassCastExcpetion

Comment: I can access the type by just doing key.type as it is defined public. This does not help though, as I am looking for a way for the getValue() function to have the proper return type. If I always return an Object I will have to go through casting hell when using that method.

Comment: What's the point of calling `cast` if you're returning `Object`? And `cast` wouldn't help anyway unless `type` is typed as `Class<T>` instead of `Class`.

Comment: Well this isnt an OO way of doing things in the first place. If you dont want to go through this whole mess maybe a redesign is in order.

Comment: What would be the proper OO way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Polymorphism, Key would be an abstract class which all the types of keys extend, with each key type you would define the conversion process for the strValue. Its bit more coding but it gives you more flexibility in the long run. Its an interesting question hope you find an answer that suits you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: You are right. It is more code but would be even cleaner than what I am doing now. I might go that route as well, thanks.