# How to design a method that has no `unchecked cast` warning in java

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-cast

I have a class named `Myclass`, which is just a wrapper of a `HashMap`, I want to be able to store the possible key/value pair listed below:

- `KEY_A` -> `MyClassA`
- `KEY_LIST_B` -> `List<MyClassB>`
- `KEY_C` -> `List<MyClassC>`

Here is my code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MYClass myClass = new MYClass();

        myClass.set(MyEnum.KEY_A, new MyClassA());
        myClass.set(MyEnum.KEY_LIST_B, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new MyClassB())));
        myClass.set(MyEnum.KEY_C, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new MyClassC())));

        MyClassA a = (MyClassA) myClass.get(MyEnum.KEY_A);
        List<MyClassB> listB = (List<MyClassB>) myClass.get(MyEnum.KEY_LIST_B);//Unchecked cast
        List<MyClassC> listC = (List<MyClassC>) myClass.get(MyEnum.KEY_C);//Unchecked cast
    }

    public static class MYClass {
        private final HashMap<MyEnum, Object> map;

        public MYClass() { map = new HashMap<>(); }

        public Object get(MyEnum key) { return map.get(key); }

        public void set(MyEnum key, Object value) { map.put(key, value); }
    }

    public static class MyClassA {}
    public static class MyClassB {}
    public static class MyClassC {}
    public enum MyEnum {KEY_A, KEY_LIST_B, KEY_C}
}
```

1. How can I design (signature of these methods) the `get()` and `set()` methods of `MyClass` to be able to store the key/value pair listed earlier and avoid the `Unchecked cast`?
2. Why this line does not have `Unchecked cast` warning even if the cast is not safe ?

   `MyClassA a = (MyClassA) myClass.get(MyEnum.KEY_A);`

Comment: (2) Because if that cast is not possible then it will fail with a `ClassCastException` at run-time. The "unchecked cast" warning is related to generics, because it's possible to change the generic type arguments via casts without getting a cast exception at run-time (e.g., you inserted a `List<String>` value but then cast the object to a `List<Integer>` when you retrieve the value, allowing you to add `Integer` to the `List<String>`).

Comment: (1) You can do the casting internally and use a generic psuedo-enum [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605285/1553851).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your reply, I thought the warning was related to `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for your reply, I don't understand what you mean by 'internal casting' and 'generic pseudo-enumeration' can you please show me some code how can I use it

Comment: @shmosel's link already gives an example.  That is the only way you might be able to accomplish something type-safe.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman, There are many answers, I don't know which one to choose and how, although I don't think the question is the same because I'm not asking about generic enumeration, in my case all keys belong to the same enumeration (`MyEnum` ) only the value and the return type can be changed.

Comment: If you cannot change the enum, then there is nothing whatsoever you can do to improve matters.  Fundamentally, the types of `function(KEY_A)` and `function(KEY_B)` must always be the same, if the types of `KEY_A` and `KEY_B` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution would be to use a generic "key class" that carries information regarding the value type. Instances of the key would have a reference to the value type's `Class`. Note your enum is close to this solution, but unfortunately you can't have a generic enum where each constant has different type arguments.

Here's an example:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Container {

  public static final Key<Foo> FOO_KEY = new Key<>(Foo.class);
  @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"}) 
  public static final Key<List<Bar>> BAR_LIST_KEY = new Key(List.class);
  @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
  public static final Key<List<Baz>> BAZ_LIST_KEY = new Key(List.class);

  private final Map<Key<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

  public <T> void put(Key<T> key, T value) {
    map.put(key, value);
  }

  public <T> T get(Key<T> key) {
    var value = map.get(key);
    return value == null ? null : key.getValueType().cast(value);
  }

  public static final class Key<T> {

    private final Class<T> valueType;

    private Key(Class<T> valueType) {
      this.valueType = valueType;
    }

    public Class<T> getValueType() {
      return valueType;
    }
  }
}
```

I personally would be okay with this implementation, as the (suppressed) warnings only occur inside `Container`. Code which uses the `Container` class won't encounter unchecked cast or raw type warnings.

The reason for the `@SuppressWarnings` annotations is because a `Class` cannot legitimately represent a *parameterized type*. In other words, you can have a `Class<List>` but not a `Class<List<Foo>>`<sup>**1**</sup>. However, if you want to avoid even suppressing these warnings, then the only approach I can think of is to create wrapper classes for your generic value types. Such as:

```java
public record MyClassBList(List<MyClassB> list) {}
```

And then have a `Key<MyClassBList>`.

As for why:

```java
MyClassA a = (MyClassA) myClass.get(MyEnum.KEY_A);
```

Does not cause an "unchecked cast" warning to be omitted, that's because there's no generics involved. If the above cast is not possible at run-time, then a `ClassCastException` would be thrown. But when generics are involved, then the cast might succeed even if you "change" the type arguments. For instance:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("Hello, World!");
map.put("key", stringList);

// This results in an "unchecked cast" warning, but the cast
// **will** succeed at run-time.
List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>) map.get("key");
integerList.add(0); // okay, because you've said it's a List<Integer>

// Now 'stringList' has a String element AND an Integer element
for (String element : stringList) {
  // this will fail at run-time (after the cast to List<Integer>
  // was successful) because the second iteration will result in
  // trying to cast an Integer to a String
  System.out.println(element);
}
```

And that mess of a situation is why they warn you about "unchecked casts". The `Container` example above should not be able to result in such problems due to how `put` and `get` are defined, unless you deliberately and explicitly try to break things (e.g., by using raw types, casting "hacks", etc.).

---

<sup>**1.** You technically can have a reference to a `Class<List<Foo>>`, by doing something similar to what I did with `Key` above, but it would not actually represent a `List<Foo>`.</sup>